# Is there a version of PSWebServiceLibrary.php running with PHP v7.0?

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop-1.6

I have site A that runs on Prestashop 1.6.1.5 and to retrieve data on another site (site B) which also runs under Prestashop 1.6.1.5, I use a module "homemade" (by my predecessor) which uses, among other things, PSWebServiceLibrary.php.
When I change version of PHP (from version 5.6 to version 7.0) on site B and I want to use the module on site A, I have some errors including PSWebServiceLibrary.php
I thus have the following error message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PrestaShopWebserviceException' with message
>   'This call to PrestaShop Web Services failed and returned an HTTP status of 500. That means: Internal Server Error.' in www.ndd.fr/PSWebServiceLibrary.php:95
>   Stack trace:

```
    0 www.ndd.fr/PSWebServiceLibrary.php(297): PrestaShopWebservice->checkStatusCode(500)
    1 www.ndd.fr/modules/orderlist/classes/orderArrayCreator.class.php(145): PrestaShopWebservice->get(Array)
    2 www.ndd.fr/modules/orderlist/controllers/admin/AdminOrderList.php(125): orderArrayCreator->createDistantOrderArray()
    3 www.ndd.fr/classes/controller/Controller.php(178): AdminOrderListController->postProcess()
    4 www.ndd.fr/override/classes/Dispatcher.php(335): ControllerCore->run()
    5 www.ndd.fr/override/classes/Dispatcher.php(107): Dispatcher->dispatch_16()
    6 www.ndd.fr/admin/index.php(58): Dispatcher->dispatch()
    7 {main} thrown in www.ndd.fr/PSWebServiceLibrary.php on line 95
```

If I come back to version 5.6, I have no problem, the module works normally.
So this is a problem related to version 7 of PHP.
Is there a version of PSWebServiceLibrary.php that works with PHP v 7.0?
In advance thank you for your help because I am a beginner in PHP

Answer (score 1):

Indeed PrestaShop 1.6.1.5 is not officially PHP 7.x compatible, however, you should be able to fix this error easily:

1. Edit the file **/classes/webservice/WebserviceRequest.php** and on line **794** replace:

   `if (count(self::$shopIDs)) {`

   by

   `if (is_array(self::$shopIDs) && count(self::$shopIDs)) {`
2. Download the latest version of **PSWebServiceLibrary.php** ([here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop-webservice-lib/master/PSWebServiceLibrary.php))
3. To make sure everything's now ok, create a new file test-ws.php with the following code (and type in your url/credentials) :

   ```
   <?php

   require_once('./PSWebServiceLibrary.php');

   try
   {
       $ws = new PrestaShopWebservice('http://www.yourstore.com', 'YOURWSKEYHERE', false);
       echo '<pre>';
       print_r($ws);
   }
   catch (PrestaShopWebserviceException $ex)
   {
       echo 'Error : '.$ex->getMessage();
   }

   ?>
   ```

   If it works you should get something like:

   `PrestaShopWebservice Object
   (
       [url:protected] => http://www.yourstore.com
       [key:protected] => YOURWSKEYHERE
       [debug:protected] => 
       [version:protected] => unknown
   )`

In case you still get a 500 error after that: Turn on error_logs in your php.ini configuration file and check the errors logs. Alternately, you can try to set _PS_MODE_DEV_ to true in /config/defines.inc.php.

Comment: Sorry Bruno. I edited the file /classes/webservice/WebserviceRequest.php and PSWebServiceLibrary.php on both sites (the master and the slave). Then, I created and tested the file test-ws.php (and type the URL of the slave site and the corresponding key). That worked. Then I turned the slave site in PHP 7, running the module on the master site, but it makes me the same mistakes.